# I have ERD And MYSQL server Can I link the ERD with the server

Tags: mysql

so as shown in the title I create a ERD using MySQL workbench and I have a MySQL server that manged by MySQL workbench.

So Can I link the ERD with The server so when I change the ERD the Database schema Changed in the server???

I found some options in database drop down list but I don't want to try because I am afraid of missing things up and lose some information.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. With your ERD open, select from the menu `Database->forward engineer`. Just complete the dialogs to connect to your server, create the db and the tables from your diagram. If you edit the diagram or the database using SQL queries, use `Database->Synchronize model` to update in either direction! It's totally safe but try it on some simple examples until you get the hang of it.